# Where is Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.AuthenticationManager in Asp.Net Identity RTM version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have installed the nightly build of the AspNet-identity assemblies from [here](http://www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightly/)

It seems that the `AuthenticationManager` class from the RC version is gone from the RTM version (*Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.1.0.0-rtm-130914*).

It used to be in the *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin* assembly, but its no longer there.

This class had the methods: `SignInAsync` and `CheckPasswordAndSignInAsync` that are used in the default project you get when creating new ASP.Net web application MVC project with Individual User Account authentication.

Where is the AuthenticationManager now? Or what to use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That class is gone, as it was basically just adding methods that generated a ClaimsIdentity and passed that into an Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager.

Instead the RTM templates have a SignIn method in the controller that looks something like this:

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Comment: how to get current user's username? User.Identity.Name is always null

Comment: That most likely means something went wrong with the sign in, and no claims principal is there.

Answer (score 4):

By all means someone correct me if I'm wrong but hasn't the AuthenticationManager been moved to

`HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication`?

and so the above example now goes:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(UserManager<User> manager, User user, bool isPersistent)
{
    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DeffaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(){ IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

Note that UserManager no longer seems to have the static method CreateIdentityAsync so this has to be fired off an object instance.

Unless I've missed something?