# How to change authentication cookies after changing UserName of current user with asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity

Using asp.net identity version 1.0.0-rc1 with Entity Framework 6.0.0-rc1 (the ones that come with Visual Studio 2013 RC).

Trying to give users an opportunity to change their `UserName`.
There seems to be no function for that under `AuthenticationIdentityManager`, so I change the data using EF (get User object for current user, change UserName and save changes).

The problem is that authentication cookies remain unchanged, and the next request fails as there is no such user.

With forms authentication in the past I used the following code to solve this.

```
var formsAuthCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var isPersistent = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsAuthCookie.Value).IsPersistent;
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUserName, isPersistent);
```

What should I do with asp.net identity to update the cookies?

**UPDATE**

The following code seems to update the authentication cookie.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);
identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst(identity.NameClaimType));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(identity.NameClaimType, newUserName));
AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant
    (new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties {IsPersistent = false});
```

The remaining problem is: how to extract `IsPersistent` value from current authentication cookie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[How do you login/authenticate a user with Asp.Net MVC5 RTM bits using AspNet.Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091157/how-do-you-login-authenticate-a-user-with-asp-net-mvc5-rtm-bits-using-aspnet-ide?rq=1)

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

For the RC1, You can use the similar code.

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
IdentityManager.Authentication.SignIn(AuthenticationManager, user.UserId, isPersistent:false);
```

For persistent value, you need to access the authentication cookie and retrieve the status.

Updated:

Use appropriate AuthenticationType used in place of "Bearer". Also make sure while issuing the signin ticket, you are setting the AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent.

```
bool isPersistent=false;
var authContext = await Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Bearer");
if (authContext != null)
{
   var aProperties = authContext.Properties;
   isPersistent = aProperties.IsPersistent;
}
```

Comment: This code may work for RTM (not widely available yet). In RC1 there are no DefaultAuthenticationTypes and UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync().

Comment: The second question: how can I get current IsPersistent value (my goal is just to change UserName, not anything else)?

Comment: Before release of VS2013, it is good to keep trials with the nightly build. Few of the comments here from developers states the many RC1 classes are not available in RTM that is going to be released with VS2013 in Nov.

Comment: I have upgraded to nightly builds, but the problem is still here: how can I get current IsPersistent value?

Comment: Your last update helped (changed "Bearer" to DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie). Marked as answer.

Comment: Important: In more recent OWIN Projects, the default template code uses DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, not DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie - that will make everything above effectively do nothing if you fail to swap this little detail in your code.