# Update User Claim not Taking Effect. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.1 with Owin and Claims authentication.

After the user changes its email I need to update the users claims, so I tried in the controller:

```
  ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
  Claim claim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);
  identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, newEmail));

  IOwinContext context = new OwinContext();

  context.Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
  context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

The Claim is changed but when I refresh the page the email claims is the original again ...

It seems the cookie is not being updated. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

And is it possible to get the value of "IsPersistent" from the identity so when I sign it again I will have the same value?

Thank You,

Miguel

Comment: I found an answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349011/how-to-change-authentication-cookies-after-changing-username-of-current-user-wit) that worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

I had this same problem, so just wanted to summarise my findings here. As Chris says, the basis of the answer is indeed here: [How to change authentication cookies after changing UserName of current user with asp.net identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349011/how-to-change-authentication-cookies-after-changing-username-of-current-user-wit) but I found that thread a bit hard to follow, and that question isn't really a direct duplicate.

To begin, get the [AuthenticationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) from the current OWIN context. Once you have that, you can get the value of "isPersistent" (and other properties from the original `SignIn` call), by calling the `AuthenticateAsync` method. Then to update the claims of the current user identity you just need to replace the value of the `AuthenticationResponseGrant` property like this:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;

// Call AddClaim, AddClaims or RemoveClaim on the user identity.

IOwinContext context = Request.GetOwinContext();

var authenticationContext = 
    await context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

if (authenticationContext != null)
{
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
        identity,
        authenticationContext.Properties);
}
```

It is the final setting of the `AuthenticationResponseGrant` property that actually updates the cookie.

Hope this helps other readers.

Comment: How do you get AuthenticationManager and AuthenticationResult from OWIN Context?

Comment: @maxim, With reference to the above sample code, `context.Authentication` (i.e.,`Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication`) will get you the current AuthenticationManager. After that call `authenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync()` to get the AuthenticationResult.

Comment: +1 for "It is the final setting of the AuthenticationResponseGrant property that actually updates the cookie."  I injected `IAuthenticationManager` directly into my class, set the `AuthenticationResponseGrant` property, and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the straight forward explanation. This was messing with my head for hours! Thank you!

One little bit of feedback; at the very end of your code, I think you meant to use `authenticationContext.Properties` instead of `authenticationResult.Properties` as `authenticationResult` doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: Worked for me but I had to change `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie` to `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**SORRY, this is an ASP.NET CORE solution**
I also challenged the problem with claims, but the answer was easy to find.

To refresh your cookie, you can rely on the RefreshSignInAsync() function of the SignInManager;

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public ApiClubController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

Inside your function:

```
//GET CURRENT USER
        var usr = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        //OLD CLAIM
        var myClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(usr);
        var oldClaim = myClaims.Where(o => o.Type.Equals("Club")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (oldClaim != null)
        {
            await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(usr, oldClaim);
        }

        //CREATE CLUB CLAIM
        var clubClaim = new Claim("Club", "" + id);
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(usr, clubClaim);

        //RESET USER COOKIE
        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(usr);

        //RETURN
        return Ok(company);;
```

**NOTE:**
I'm using an API here, because I'm mixing up a lot with angular.
If you update your identity with your API, you need to refresh your page in order to view things based on your claim

Comment: What assembly is the RefreshSignInAsync method in?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Comment: How does this compare to `await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);`?

I'm at a loss as to which one to use.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. Not sure if it is the best way but the updated claim is in the DB and in subsequent controllers.

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
var c = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Type == "tId");
await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, c);
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("tId", "9032C945-DC5C-4FC9-BE7C-8EDC83A72E58"));

AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

Comment: This works for me finally. I think I was blocked by the list of Claims. Maybe it should use the method ``UserManager.GetClaimsAsync`` in order to avoid exception Enumerator foreach during ``RemoveClaimAsync``. Holp this will be help to others.

Comment: This is the only way I could get claims to update.  Thanks!