# Implementing remember me with .NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, remember-me

I have wrote a code like following:

```
   if (user.PasswordHash == Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, user.PasswordSalt))
                        {

                            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Email));
                            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
                            var roles = user.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId).ToList();

                            foreach (var item in roles)
                            {
                                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Roles.RoleName));
                            }
                            identity.AddClaims(claims);
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email));

                            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                        }
```

Inside my model I have the remember me property which I want to incorporate upon user login, how can I do that?

P.S. The value is bool and I just need to somehow now tell the browser what the user picked from the login menu...

Comment: I think this answer might get you going in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091157/how-do-you-login-authenticate-a-user-with-asp-net-mvc5-rtm-bits-using-aspnet-ide

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

...

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(){IsPersistent = model.RememberMe}, identity);
```

Comment: also, you need to add this too:
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

Comment: You can edit your post with that edit link underneath it.  Four space indent for code samples.