# ASP.Net MVC 5 w/identity 2.2.0 Log off not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, logout, asp.net-identity-2

I am using a the basic login on a test ASP.Net MVC 5 site (for an internet site).

The login works fine but when I try to logout it doesn't happen.
The logout link does call the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

But the user stays logged in. How do I ensure that the user actually gets logged out?

Comment: Can be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263095/logout-functionality-not-working-with-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had this problem before, change:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

To:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Assuming that you are using **ApplicationCookie** to store your login information.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me. Small note: it should be `AuthenticationManager` (per the auto-generated code) and not `Authentication`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't log out from the server side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552448/web-api-2-owin-authentication-signout-doesnt-logout

Comment: @JeevaJsb that question is about bearer tokens, which are completely different from cookies

Answer (score 4):

Better way :

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "support", new { area = "" });
}
```

or you can use injected SignInManager into your controller like this :

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    _signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "support", new { area = "" });
}
```

there is no deference.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem of not being able to logout.  I would stay logged in and only redirect back to the home view.  I was using Chrome and I tried it in firefox and ie and didn't have the problem.  Then I cleared my cookies in chrome and it all worked fine.  It could be a quick and easy first step if other encounter this problem.

Comment: We encountered the same issue with our application after upgrading from AspNet.Identity 2.0.1 to 2.2.0.  Clearing cookies indeed signed the user out, but it was not a very practical solution.  We implemented the fix in the accepted answer and it resolved the problem for us.