# ASP.NET Identity 2 SignOut Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

The sign out is not working when using ASP.NET Identity 2.0. It works sometimes. We have to frequently hit the LogOff action twice for it to actually log off. Debugging locally works fine. It has the issue on the live servers. Any ideas? Here's our LogOff method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "General");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC 5 w/identity 2.2.0 Log off not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642284/asp-net-mvc-5-w-identity-2-2-0-log-off-not-working). Try a solution from there.

Comment: That was working, but has stopped. Someone from the team is investigating.