# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo returns null except in ExternalLoginCallback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using the standard MVC template in VS2013 and have enabled external logins.  It works fine, and I am now adding some features.

I find that `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo` works fine in the ExternalLoginCallback action.  However, if I have it anywhere else, it always returns null, even if the user is logged in. I did a test by adding the following in the Account controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        Debug.Assert(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        ViewBag.Provider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
        return View();
    }
```

The Account controller requires authorization but I added the Authorize attribute just to be doubly sure.  I tried with both Twitter and Google accounts (user has to be successfully logged in to execute this code), GetExernalLoginInfo will always return null in the above method.  I have only external accounts, and there are no accounts with local passwords so there is no chance that a local user was logged in by accident.

Why does it not work? Doesn't GetExternalLoginInfo derive the result from the cookies?

Edits: Applying the `UseKentorOwinCookieSaver` patch from [ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser) didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried checking Fiddler to see what is coming back from the external login sources? It might give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: @Josh, yes, but the query string parameters and cookies are encrypted, and there is no documentation on what each is doing.

Comment: I think this is intended, you are supposed to create a session in ExternalLoginCallback. But for me, I am not even getting value out of GetExternalLoginInfo in the ExternalLoginCallback.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the MVC template uses the SignInManager class. Because of that, by default all users are signed in locally, also after logging in with an external account.

In the ExternalLoginCallback method there is the following line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

This signs out the external userinfo, and signs in the local user with an ApplicationCookie. 
If you take a look at the AuthenticationManager after this line is executed, you will see an AuthenticationResponseGrant.AuthentityType=ApplicationCookie and AuthenticationResponseRevoke.AuthenticationType=ExternalCookie.

Eventually the ExternalCookie is removed when the Owin middleware inspects the context. 
That way AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null after logging in, the cookie holding the info has been removed and replaced by a ApplicationCookie.