# Getting the external login information from User object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, claims-based-identity

Environment: MVC project using the standard web template from VS2013

When a user is signed in via an external login, eg Google, is it possible to retrieve information about the external login, eg LoginProvider, DefaultUserName, etc, from the Controller's `User` object (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)?

If not this object, is there any other means to get them within a MVC controller?

Comment: I don't  think it works from the `user` object directly. There is a really good explanation of how to retreive information for 3rd party login in this installment of the MVC5 fundamentas tutorial by Scott Allen, http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

Answer (score 2):

In the `AcountsController` look for the action called `ExternalLoginCallback`. There is a line of code as such

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

The `loginInfo` instance only contains only the basic information that your application needs to authenticate you. But if you call

```
var detailedLoginInfo = AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

this instance should contain all the information you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question because GetExternalLoginInfo didn't work for me as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812347/authenticationmanager-getexternallogininfo-returns-null-except-in-externalloginc. The AuthenticateAsync method in the PluralSight video also does not work outside ExternalLoginCallback.

Comment: But could you not call that method there, in the `ExternalLoginCallback`,  and store the information for later use?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have to do.  I wanted to avoid it because it would mean exposing everything on the query string parameters as control passes from one RedirectToAction to another.

Comment: You could also store it in a Db, or put it in a static class