# ASP.net Identity stops handing out External Cookie after removing external account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a site setup with four 3rd-party login services, Microsoft, VS, Github, and Linkedin. Everything seems to work great, I can log in/out, add/remove external accounts with no problem.

Randomly however, it seems to stop working. When I try to login using any of the 3rd-party services, it just kicks me back to the login page.

Looking at the `ExternalLoginCallback` it appears that the `AuthenticateResult.Identity` is `null` and it can't get the external login info. Looking at it on the client-side it looks like they never got the `external signin cookie`.

<strike>I still can't consistently reproduce this error, so it's really hard to determine what might be happening. Any help would be great.</strike>

**Update 1:** I was able to identify the steps to reproduce:

1. Login to an account with more than 1 associated login
2. Remove one of the logins
3. In a new browser or a private session, try to log in with any of the 3rd-party accounts and you will be returned to login without an external cookie.

After hitting the error it won't hand out a cookie to any new sessions until IIS is restarted.

**Update 2:** Looks like it has something to do with setting a Session variable.

On the `removeLogin` action I was adding a value to the session. I'm not sure why but when I stopped doing that, I stopped having my problem. Time to figure out why... **Update 3:** Looks like this problem has been [reported to the Katana Team](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197)

**Update 4:** Looks like someone else already ran into this problem. [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser). They didn't give all of the code you needed to solve it, so I'll include that here as an answer.

---

`Startup.Auth.cs`

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {

    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(appContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
            )
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions{
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSA:Id"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSA:Secret"],
        Caption = "Microsoft"
    });

    app.UseVisualStudioAuthentication(new VisualStudioAuthenticationOptions(){
        AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSO:Id"],
        AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VSO:Secret"],
        Provider = new VisualStudioAuthenticationProvider(){
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>{
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:vso:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "VisualStudio"));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:vso:refresh_token", context.RefreshToken, XmlSchemaString, "VisualStudio"));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        },
        Caption = "Visual Studio"
    });

    app.UseGitHubAuthentication(new GitHubAuthenticationOptions{
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GH:Id"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GH:Secret"],
        Caption = "Github"
    });

    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions {
        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LI:Id"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LI:Secret"],
        Caption = "LinkedIn"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OWIN and asp.net handle cookies/session differently. If you authorize with OWIN before you initialize a session, anyone after a session is initialized will not  be able to login.

**Workaround:** Add the following to your `Global.asax`

```
// Fix for OWIN session bug
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState() {
        Session["Workaround"] = 0;
    }
}
```

**Long term:** The way OWIN and asp.net handle sessions/cookies will be merged in vNext, use the work around until then...

Comment: To avoid Exception if session isn't avaible in current context, I suggest to check context and session too before setting value             HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context != null && context.Session != null)
            {
                if (Session["Workaround"] != null)
                {
                    Session["Workaround"] = 0;
                }
            }

Comment: @EnricoTirotta - do you have a typo in your null check?  Should it be  if (Session["Workaround"] == null) { Session["Workaround"] = 0; }