# Azure AD B2C Token returns name but User.Identity.Name is null

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C token that seems to be correctly returning the currently logged-in user's name. Here is a screenshot from jwt.ms which I am using to decode the token returned by the application after I have logged in:

[image]

However, then I attempt to use `@User.Identity.Name` in my `_Layout.cshtml`. Why is it null? Shouldn't it be equal to the "name" value in the screenshot?

Comment: You may need to tell the middleware where to find the `Name` but it would depend on the middleware your using.

Comment: I'm using the following: `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();`. That that what you mean by "middleware"?

Comment: Curious... why are you using [Kentor.OwinCookieSaver](https://github.com/Sustainsys/owin-cookie-saver)?

Comment: @spottedmahn I was using it "just in case" this was the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720820/application-stops-generating-login-cookies. I can probably remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out I was missing the line marked by the comments:

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                },

                //////// WAS MISSING THIS BELOW /////////
                // Specify the claims to validate
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // This claim is in the Azure AD B2C token; this code tells the web app to "absorb" the token "name" and place it in the user object
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId} {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}"
            }
        );
```

The entire file is located here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Comment: FYI, the [comment has been updated](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/pull/30) :)  `// Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.`

Answer (score 1):

See [this working example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) that is using Owin (which it sounds like you're using).

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a id="profile-link">@User.Identity.Name</a>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Source](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L6)

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

        ...
    );
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L53)