# Owin Cookie with JSON value malformed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

We have a asp.net mvc application that uses SignalR. SignalR is hosted in a SelfHosted Service using OWIN.

I have created a cookie on the MVC side, the cookie content is a JSON string of a the following class:

```
public class UserCookie
{
    public int    UserId    { get; set; }
    public string Username  { get; set; }
}
```

I create the cookie in the MVC Controller:

```
var userCookie = new UserCookie
{
  UserId   = 999999,
  Username = "John Doe"
};

var serializeValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userCookie);

Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie("MyCookie", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userCookie)));
```

I can see the Cookie value in Chrome and Fiddler:

[image]

I Can Deserialize the cookie on the MVC side:

[image]

But on the SelfHosted OWIN side I get the following error:

[image]

It seems like the OWIN side only gets part of the cookie as the value is `{\"UserId\":999999`

Here is my startup class for OWIN:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) 
    {   
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);            

        app.Use(async (context, next) => 
        {
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Common.Users.UserCookie>(context.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"]);

            await next();
        });

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Common.Users.UserCookie>(context.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"]);` is where I am getting the error.

Must I encode the cookie value for it to work on the OWIN side? Or is there something obvious that I am missing?

**UPDATE**

Encoding the JSON as base64 and using it as the value for the cookie(instead of the JSON value) seems to solve the issue as I can now successfully deserialize the cookie value.

Comment: [Possible OWIN bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser)

Comment: You should not be using JSON in a cookie, it uses invalid characters. I recomend Base64 or Url encoding the value.

Comment: @Tratcher I will keep that in mind but this still does not explain why MVC can deserialize the value and OWIN can not?

Comment: The parsing behavior for invalid data is undefined, so you will get different results with different parsers.