# ASP.NET MVC owin oauth login won't work from different machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I'm having a weird problem with logging using owin oauth in my test environment.
I create an account from my PC at the office using Google and I'm not able to use the same Google account to login from home or my mobile phone. 
That happens with Facebook as well.

**Setup:**

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            /* Local login implementation  */
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3),
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            /* Login with Google */
            var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = "",
            };
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);          
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        }
    }
```

**Oauth Controller**

```
public class oauthcontroller : basecontroller
{
    private readonly IUserService  _userService;

    // Google login button click
    public ActionResult google()
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(LoginProviderEnum.Google.DisplayName, "/oauth/callback");
    }

    public ActionResult callback()
    {   
       // context is not null
        var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        // auth is null
        var auth = context.Authentication;
        var loginInfo = auth.GetExternalLoginInfo();
        //...
    }        
}
```

When using my PC at work this works fine and when logging from different machine HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication is null.

**UPDATE**: I managed to reproduce it in localhost by removing cookie **ASP.Net_SessionId**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very well described here:
[ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser/21234614#21234614)

Quick and dirty fix:

```
// Google login button click
public ActionResult google()
{
    Session["RunSession"] = "1"; // Quick FIX
    return new ChallengeResult(LoginProviderEnum.Google.DisplayName, "/oauth/callback");
}
```