# Azure AD API returns System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity.IsAuthenticated as false always

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to integrate my web service to authenticate using Azure AD. The response from Azure AD varies each time. When i open my site in firefox normal browser, the IsAuthenticated as true.

[IsAuthenticatedAsTrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAURq.png)

Opening in a private browser, the IsAuthenticated is false.

[IsAuthenticatedAsFalse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4qWE.png)

The only difference i can see is, the IsAuthenticated true is from ClaimsIdentity and IsAuthenticated false is from GenericIdentity.

The following is my startup.auth code.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
}
```

The following is my code to send the authentication request to AzureAD

```
    public void LoginUsingAzure()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you opened a private window and then didn't sign in? Because the private window does not share sessions with the other window.

Comment: this issue is also reproduced in normal window. after logging in to my site in normal browser, then clearing the cache and cookies in the browser, and when i try to login again, i face this issue. this issue reproduces in all the browsers. Is there anything i need to configure in Azure AD portal ?

Comment: By clearing the cookies aren't you also clearing the ASP.NET authentication cookie? Isn't it a bit expected that it would then say you are not authenticated? The GenericIdentity being there just means you have not authenticated yet.

Comment: after clearing my cookies and reloading the page, i was redirected to the office 365 login page, and i was asked to sign in again. after signing in successfully, the page redirects to my site login page, where i can notice the isauthenticated is set to false. i cant able to login again once i cleared my cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed. The reason for this issue is dependency problem. Found the answer in the below stackoverflow link.

[ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser)

Installing Kentor.OwinCookieSaver -Version 1.1.0 nuget package, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce this issue however failed. I am testing the web app using version `50.1.0` with clean installation.

To fix this issue, I suggest that you re-install the Firefox with this version.

Here is the test figure for your reference:

[image]

Comment: I reinstalled my firefox, and am using 51.0.13 version. but i still face this issue. Can i know, what type of authentication do you use ? is it openid or oauth?

Comment: I was testing [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) using the openId connect.

Comment: I can still reproduce my issue. I have used the same code sample for implementation. after logging in to my site, then clearing the cache and cookies in the browser, and when i try to login again, i face this issue.  Is there anything i need to configure in Azure AD portal ?