# OWIN External Cookie disappearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies, saml-2.0

Intermittently our External authentication cookies are not returning.
We are using

1. OWIN as the middleware layer
2. .Net 4.62
3. SessionState
4. Systain SAML
5. 2 IIS Web Servers

The following links refer to what I believe the problem is

http://appetere.com/post/owinresponse-cookies-not-set-when-remove-an-httpresponse-cookie

[ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser)

I've tried setting the session as follows `Session["Workaround"] = 0;`

We initialize the Cookie as follows

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
{ 
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie("ExternalCookie");
    ...etc
```

On the callback we get the result as follows

```
AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await this.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
```

I'd like to try using the following mentioned in the links above to resolve it `OnSendingHeaders(state => {...` but I'm unsure of how to implement it