# ASP.Net Identity MVC 5 Login to Google only works under IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have created an MVC 5 application (following the Create an ASP.NET MVC 5 App with Facebook and Google OAuth2 and OpenID Sign-on tutorial) and uncommented the line:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

Everything works fine. I can login using Google. I then change the project properties to host the application under my local IIS server (instead of the default IIS Express). The Google login no longer works. The line:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

in ExternalLoginCallback always returns a null, whereas under IIS Express loginInfo is populated. This means the browser is just bounced back to the Login page. I'm running on Windows 8.1.

I have seen other people having issues with null exceptions, I don't get any. I have restarted IIS. I have rebooted my machine and still I get the same result.

Comment: What identity are you running your worker process as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just managed to solve this for a project I am working on as detailed [on my blog](http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2014/06/24/tough-mvc-5-owin-external-authentication-issue/).
The solution seems to be to either turn off Session state

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

or to ensure that users have a value in their Session before the external login is performed,

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    //Ensure Session has at least one value
    Session["EnableExternalAuth"] = true;

    return View();
}
```

There is an Owin cookie issue/bug which is probably the root cause

- [ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser/21234614#21234614)

and the following StackOverflow questions are also related:

- [OWIN OpenID provider - GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535146/owin-openid-provider-getexternallogininfo-returns-null)
- [ASP.NET MVC 5 (VS2013 final): Facebook login with OWIN fails (loginInfo is null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453293/asp-net-mvc-5-vs2013-final-facebook-login-with-owin-fails-logininfo-is-null)

Comment: Fantastic, the dummy session value worked a treat. Amazing that it is still a bug in the template but kudos to Tomas Dolezal for finding the work around.

Answer (score 0):

See the  [Technovert article](http://blog.technovert.com/2014/01/google-openid-integration-issues-asp-net-identity/) where they discuss adding a location permission subsection to the web.config file.

This solves some of the issues anyway