# Google Authentication stops working after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-authentication

We are facing a strange issue here. We have asp.net application that allows users to sing in using google. Every thing works fine on local , But when we deploy the app to production and user tries to login using google it just redirects them back to login page.

Now the strange thing comes in place. After deployment when we modify the web.config file by even adding a space it starts working for some time allowing users to login using google. But after a certain period of time it again stops working.

So if we modify the web.config again it again works for some time.

Any one ever has come across such issue ? I have been pulling my hair since last 2 days but could not get rid of this issue. Please suggest anything useful.

```
 *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>             
  <location path="Administration">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />        
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms protection="All" loginUrl="Account/login.aspx"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Administration/Company/ManageCompany.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SendGrid.SmtpApi" publicKeyToken="2ae73662c35d80e4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.1.0" newVersion="1.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging.Core" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>        
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <elmah>       
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" />
  </elmah>
  <system.net>

  </system.net>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>*
```

Comment: How much is "some time" and "a certain amount of time"?

Comment: Sounds like something is cached. When the web.config changes, the application pool is recycled and the cache is cleared and everything starts working again. I've seen something like this a few years ago, can't remember what was done to resolve it though... Are any errors or warnings showing in the event viewer of the server?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That probably works 4-5 hours and then stops.

Comment: @user1666620 Yes you are right. We also know that when web.config is updated , app pool is restarted. But still not able to figure out what is causing this issue.

Comment: @SachinTrivedi are there any errors or warnings or information messages logged at the times of failure, either by the application or by the event viewer?

Comment: @user1666620 I will check and let you know when this issue happens again. I should look under Windows Logs => Application correct ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi yes - though check the other categories as well. There's no reason you can't check for warning or errors from earlier though.

Comment: @user1666620 i don't see any errors right now from the past events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by setting dummy session value.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    Session["dummy"] = "dummy"; // Create ASP.NET_SessionId cookie

    return View();
}
```

You can find more details here : [OWIN OpenID provider - GetExternalLoginInfo() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535146/owin-openid-provider-getexternallogininfo-returns-null)